# need to my server's ip changes when it needs to connect port 'x' on ip 'y'

Tags: linux, iptables, proxy, ip, port

I have a linux server and have a proxy server on another machine.

My linux server needs connect to port 'x' on ip 'y'

Is it possible to create iptables rule or another way to: when my linux server tries to connect to port 'x' on ip 'y' uses my proxy server on another machine?

In other words, I need to my server's ip changes when it needs to connect port 'x' on ip 'y' by using another proxy server machine.

simple question: "need a way to proxify a port"

Comment: Just cutting and pasting your question back in when it's rejected doesn't accomplish anything but annoying people.  Figure out why it was rejected and fix it.

Comment: @geekosaur i have sent it to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266676/need-to-my-servers-ip-changes-when-it-needs-to-connect-port-x-on-ip-y it says: "This question might be better asked on serverfault.com"

Comment: simple question: "need a way to proxify a port"

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect traffic to a port on the local machine like this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8000
```

You can't redirect traffic to an arbitrary machine though, see the comment at the bottom of http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//NAT-HOWTO-6.html (which still seems to be valid - I tested it)

Given this restriction, you might be able to place a reverse proxy on the local machine to forward your HTTP requests to the proxy. Nginx should be able to do this, see http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766288369/using-nginx-reverse-proxy

Whether this works or not will probably depend on how your proxy is configured...

Comment: 1. is it possible to change 127.0.0.1:8000 to an external ip:port ?

Comment: 2. 8000 is port of proxy server?

Comment: 3. if your solution work, i can config proxy server to use cascade proxy

Comment: It's not possible to change 127.0.0.1:8000 to an external port, the packets will not be rewritten correctly. Yes, 8000 is the port of the proxy server